# Получить в консоли DOM элемент с атрибутами и потомками

Tags: javascript, html

Есть элемент `input` следующего вида:

```
<input type ="radio"  name ='confidant' id = 'confidant1' value='1' onchange ='setConfidant(this);'>
```

В JavaScript я ввожу следующий код:

```
label = document.querySelector('label[for ='+ element.id +']');
console.log('label = '+ label);
```

Получаю в консоли:

```
label = [object HTMLLabelElement]
```

Что не очень информативно. Я замечал, что можно вывести в консоль элемент примерно как он написал в HTML документе: с атрибутами `id`, `name`, `value` и т.д. и просмотреть у элемента вложенные теги прямо в консоли, раскрывающимся списком (если бы они у элемента есть). Но что-то я этот момент упустил, как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При конкатенации элемент преобразуется в строку.
Чтобы увидеть элемент(со вложенными элементами), выводите только элемент:

```
console.log(label);
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо. А можно этот момент обойти? Сложно ориентироваться в консоли без указателей.

Comment: Насколько знаю, невозможно.
Можно ещё через запятую выводить значения переменных, но консоль при этом добавляет символ новой строки:
console.log('label = ', label);

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` может принимать несколько параметров, поэтому для вывода и строки `label` и удобного вида для элемента достаточно передавать их как два параметра:

```
console.log('label', label);
```